# Bash tab completion finds binary, binary can be run, but which doesn't find it. What's wrong?

Tags: macos, bash

I have a binary which shows up in tab completion, which I can run like `$ myBinary`, but the `which` tool cannot find it, and neither can other tools I'm running in bash which need to find it. What did I do wrong? I've tried copying it to `/usr/local/bin/` but no luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On bash you should use "type -a myBinary" to check where the executable can be found.

I would guess your which tool is a shell script, ignoring your $PATH variable. "type -a which" will tell you the path for further investigation.

Comment: That found it, but `which` is a binary so a dead end there unfortunately